# GeckoFx after using Xpcom.Shutdown(), Xpcom.Initialize(path) can not be used any more

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, geckofx

I would like to have more then one gecko browser in my C# app.

So what I did:

FORM UI code:

```
public partial class GeckoBrowserForm : Form
    {
        static GeckoBrowserForm()
        {   
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        }

        public GeckoBrowserForm(string xulRunnerPath, string url)
        {
            InitializeXulRunner(xulRunnerPath);
            m_Url = url;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Location = new Point(0, 0);
            Size = new Size(800, 800);
            Done = false;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private static void InitializeXulRunner(string path)
            {
                if (!Xpcom.IsInitialized)
                {
                    Xpcom.Initialize(path);
                }
            }

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{

    m_GeckoWebBrowser.Parent = this;
    m_GeckoWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    m_GeckoWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, ee) =>
    {
        var geckoDomElement = m_GeckoWebBrowser.Document.DocumentElement;
        if (geckoDomElement is GeckoHtmlElement)
        {
            GeckoHtmlElement element = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoDomElement;
            DocumentDomHtml = element.InnerHtml;
        }

        if (m_Url.Equals(m_GeckoWebBrowser.Document.Url.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Done = true;
        }
    };

    m_GeckoWebBrowser.Navigate(m_Url);
}
```

and in worker thread, not UI:

```
if (Xpcom.IsInitialized)
{
    Xpcom.Shutdown();
}

using (GeckoBrowserForm geckoBrowserForm = new GeckoBrowserForm(XulRunnerPath, propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString()))
{
    geckoBrowserForm.Show();

    while (!geckoBrowserForm.Done)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }


    string html = geckoBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
    {
        propertyBag.GetResponse = () => new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html));
    }

    base.Process(crawler, propertyBag);
}
```

problemis that after I use `Xpcom.Shutdown();` I can not use `Xpcom.Initialize(path);` any more. Program just stopped without any error.

Why?

I know what geckoFx can be only used in the same UI thread that way I want to initialite it again

```
public static void AssertCorrectThread()
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId != _XpcomThreadId)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("GeckoFx can only be called from the same thread on which it was initialized (normally the UI thread).");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Xpcom.Shutdown(); doesn't undo all the native initialization that Xpcom.Initialize performs. (for example global vars that exist in xul.dll). If you could force the firefox/xulrunner dlls to be unloaded (FreeLibrary?) after the call to Xpcom.Shutdown this MAY reset the native memory space in the process and allow another Xpcom.Initialize call.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is still a problem, which matters a great deal when unit testing.  Run all unit tests (which start with an initialize), and everything is fine.  Attempt to run them again, and you potentially run into issues, depending on the state of xpCom, because there's no way to shutdown.

similar issue here: [Using GeckoFX in a multithreaded application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490164/using-geckofx-in-a-multithreaded-application)